# Confusion on the concept of Boltzmann brain

Tags: cosmology, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I heard that a [Boltzmann brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain) is a brain-like object that materialized from random fluctuations of particle fields, where particles randomly "pop into existence" and just so happened to form a brain.

Is there some special conditions required for this proposed phenomenon?

If not, why isn't there random objects, or at least random particles entering and exiting existence all over the place? and wouldn't that be a violation of the conservation of energy?

Comment: sorry, there are so many things wrong in this post that I don't know where to begin... I mean, sentence by sentence it is just nonsense. That's not what a Boltzmann brain is. Particles don't randomly pop into existence. The proposed phenomenon makes no sense, it cannot happen under no special condition whatsoever. I could go on but I guess you get what I mean.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform There's nothing wrong with this question. The particles that "pop into existence" are just the collapse of extremely spread out wave functions.

Comment: First question: No, it could happen anywhere at any time. Second: Because, almost by definition, it's extremely unlikely. Third: No, the energy was always there. When you observe, the wave functions that were extremely spread out simply collapse. It's just that you weren't observing the particles before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what a Boltzmann brain is. Starting at the very beginning: entropy must always stay the same or increase over time, according to the second law of thermodynamics. However, Boltzmann (the Ludwig one, not the brain one) formulated a version of the law of entropy that was statistical. What this means for what you're asking is that while entropy almost always increases or stays the same, over billions of billions of billions of billions of billions...you get the idea years, entropy might go down a bit. This is called a *fluctuation*.

So backing up a tad, if entropy always increases/stays the same, what is surprising for cosmologists is that the universe started in such a low-entropy state. So to (try) to explain this, Boltzmann said, hey, what if there's a bigger universe that our universe is in, and it is in a state of the most possible entropy, or thermal equilibrium. Then, let's say it exists for a long long time, those billions we talked about earlier. There'll be statistical fluctuations, right? And those statistical fluctuations might be represented by the birth of universes. Ahem, our universe is one of them.

So now, we get into the brains. Our universe must be a *HUGE* statistical fluctuation comparatively to other fluctuations. I mean, think about it. If it is so nuts for entropy to decrease by just a little tiny bit, how nuts would it be for it to decrease enough for the *birth of a universe* to happen!? So the question is, why aren't we just brains? That is, why aren't we a statistical fluctuation just big enough for intelligent life to develop, look around, see it exists, and melt back into goop. And it is this goopy-not-long-existing intelligent life that is a Boltzmann brain. This is a huge challenge to the Boltzmann (Ludwig) theory.

Now to address the mistakes in your question. Boltzmann brains don't just pop into existence from particle fields, they don't violate the laws of conservation, or anything, they just come into being kind of like we did, just for a shorter period of time, and at a lower intelligence scale, that is, the theoretical minimum for thought. You seem to be very confused about what you mean, and you kind of seem to be talking about a messed up version of virtual particles or something, which is very different.

Hope that cleared some things up! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: +1 for the summary, which saved me a lot of time getting the picture.  But I doubt if poor depressed Boltzmann, fighting every day to be taken seriously, ever said "hey"  in his entire life. : ) Lovely answer, thanks for posting.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to talk about fluctuations in quantum fields giving rise to Boltzmann brains. Conservation of energy is not violated. The particles that "pop into existence" are just the collapse of extremely spread out wave functions.

Comment: Boltzmann didn't know about the Big Bang.  He believed the universe to be infinitely old.   He did know about the earlier universe having less entropy.  So in a hypothetical universe that was infinitely old (which ours is not) Boltzmann's observation that probabilities of regions of low entropy are inversely probable to the size of the region.  So very large regions of low entropy are incalculably  improbable (and fleeting). So regions of low entropy if at all, are likely to be smaller, even to the point of merely being the observer itself.  Add to that the universe isn't infinitely old now ..